# How to get logs from all pods in a Kubernetes job?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using a Kubernetes job to run a test; a shell script runs the job and has setup/teardown logic. The job has

- `restartPolicy: Never`
- `backoffLimit: 2`

which means that if the job fails, it'll make a new pod and try again once.

After the job completes, I'd like to dump the logs from all pods in the job. But when I do

```
kubectl logs job/my-test
```

I only get logs from one of the pods, prefixed with something like `Found 2 pods, using pod/my-test-ntb4w`.

The `--all-containers=true` flag doesn't give me logs from all pods.

How can I get logs from all pods in a job, in a shell script?

Comment: One way would be to use: https://github.com/wercker/stern

Answer (score 6):

As an reference please take a look at `kubectl logs --help`:

```
   -- kubectl logs job/my-job
   # Return snapshot logs from first container of a job named hello
      kubectl logs job/hello -- will provide output only for one pod/container
    
   -- while using (either label or selector) it gives you more flexible way to deal with your resources
   # -l, --selector='': Selector (label query) to filter on.
```

Alternatively you can add custom ***labels*** or use an _***label/selector*** from job description:

```
labels:
      controller-uid: 55d965d0-0016-42ba-b4f5-120c1a78798b
      job-name: pi
```

---

You can find fairly similar case in the docs: [checking on the output of all jobs at once](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/parallel-processing-expansion/#create-jobs-from-the-manifests) and [Running an example Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/).

While using bash you can try also:

```
pods=$(kubectl get pods --selector=job-name=pi --output=jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}')

for pod in $pods ; do kubectl logs $pod ; done
```

---

Very useful command for working with k8s objects:

```
kubectl get pods,jobs --show-labels

NAME           READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE   LABELS
pod/pi-25vcd   0/1     Completed   0          97s   controller-uid=55d965d0-0016-42ba-b4f5-120c1a78798b,job-name=pi
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `--selector` instead of just `job/my-test` seems to get logs from all pods:

```
kubectl logs --selector job-name=my-test
```